# Understanding the perceptron algorithm in the book "A Course in Machine Learning"

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, perceptron

The following text is from Hal Daumé III's ["*A Course in Machine Learning*"](http://ciml.info/dl/v0_9/ciml-v0_9-ch03.pdf) online text book (Page-41).

[image]

I understand that $D$ is the size of the input vector $x$.

1. What is $y$? Why is it introduced in the algorithm? How/where/when is the initial value of $y$ given?
2. What is the rationale of testing $ya \leq 0$ for updating weights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Y is the desired output of the perceptron (often referred to as target) , for the given set of input vectors.

**Rationale behind Y.a<=0** :

Prerequisite knowledge :

- **A**=**A**-**B** : Moves vector **A** away from direction of vector **B**
- **A**=**A**+**B** : Moves **A** in the direction of **B**
- **A** (.) **B** >0 ; **A** vector is directed acutely (<90 deg.) towards **B** vector
- **A** (.) **B** <0 ; **A** vector is directed away from (>90 deg.) from **B** vector [(.) denotes dot (scalar) product and **bold** letters indicate vectors]
- **W** is augmented vector (includes threshold as another weight along with normal input weights)
- **X** is augmented input (includes -1 as extra input (corresponding to threshold) along with other normal inputs
- a(activation) = **W** (.) **X**
- a >=0 ; Perceptron output 1
- a<0 ; Perceptron output -1 (**Not zero** as implicit in the given algorithm I think)

Now Rationale :

(Y.a<0)

This means 
Either of the following :

- Y=-1 and a>0 ; in this case the target output is -1 but as a>0 so the Perceptron outputs 1. So we must move the weight vector away from this set of input vector, so that angle between them increases and the dot product (a) becomes < 0 so that we can get the target output.
  Hence : **W**=**W**-**X**

Or ,**W**=**W** + (-1)***X**
Or, **W**=**W**+Y**X**

- Y=1 and a<0

This means the target output is 1 but as the activation is <0 so Perceptron is outputting -1. So we must move the weight vector close to this set of input vector so that the activation can become >0 (angle decreases) and the Perceptron can output the desired output.
So :
**W** = **W**+**X**
Or **W**=**W** + Y**X**

Again , Y.a=0 is a boundary case.
By now I think you can understand the rationale behind Y.a=0. If any doubt , comment to this answer , I will explain it.

Sorry for so much long answer though. :) :)

Comment: Is that $W(.)A = = W^T.A $?

Comment: What are A and T in the above comment?

Comment: Sorry for that, W(.)X == W^T.X. I.e. dot product of transpose of W with X.

Comment: No they won't be same until you perform transpose on both the vectors. [ Although I assume that by transpose you mean reversing the components of the vectors. I.e , xi+yj+zk -> zi+yj+xk ] as transpose is inherent concept with matrix not vectors.